# Certainty of modal-verbs

Tags: modal-verbs

Suppose someone is knocking on my door,

My mom ask me: Who is it?

Me: That'll be Rihanna. / That would be Rihanna. / That should be Rihanna. / That is Rihanna.

Which is most certain, and which is least?

Comment: Thx, I edit it. @snailplane

Answer (score 2):

Okay, we go one by one. I'm keeping the context in mind.

> That'll be Rihanna - you are pretty sure (will implies sureness here - I **will** do this work - you are pretty sure doing it). 
>   That would be Rihanna - Could be same as the above one BUT you also add a [probability](http://www.englishforums.com/English/LetMeaningWould/xkjgl/post.htm) of that someone being Rihana here. 
>   That should be Rihanna - You are expecting her and at this time, no one else but Rihanna is there. (She's very punctual!). 
>   That is Rihanna -there's no doubt that she is Rihanna (*say* you are probably seeing her through the glass-door or CCTV!).

Out of **given all,** *That is Rihana* sounds the most certain way to tell that *she is Rihanna* and no one else. To me, the least is the sentence with *would be*. I feel that microscopically would/should/must etc. are your expectations, wishes or beliefs but when you say **"is"**, it's the reality in such case. Check the example I gave there of the CCTV or a glass-door where you don't use anything but **is Rihanna**.

Comment: What about **That must be Rihanna**? Any implicit situation?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng an intensified version of *that should be Rihanna*.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are equivalent. They express a certainty from the gut that the knock is from Rihanna. The third option expresses the possibility (however slight) that the knock *isn't* Rihanna.

And in response to the edit, the fourth option: "That is Rihanna" is the surest statement of all. Maybe Rihanna could be seen from a window?